# Upload fails on dynamic created sections

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, wordpress

I have a php function that creates dynamic sections. Each section has a input element and a different data-type to identify the kind of document is being uploaded. My goal is to make file upload automatic once the user has selected a file in a section. My Ajax code is able to pass all the data to my backend php. However, I am **not able to upload** to folder I have assigned. I can confirm that the permissions are correct. Can anyone tell me what went wrong?

**JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```
   $(document).on('change', '.fileinput', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();



    var doctype = $(this).closest('div').data('type');
    console.log(doctype);

    var file_data = $("#"+doctype).prop("files")[0];

    var form = new FormData();
    form.append("user", ajaxobject.user_id);
    form.append("file_data", file_data);
    form.append("doctype", doctype);
    form.append("action", "upload_submit_docs");

    console.log(file_data);

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxobject.ajaxurl,
        cache: false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("success callback");
            console.log("doctype= "+response.doctype);
            console.log("user= "+response.user);
            console.log("form_data= "+response.form_data);
            console.log("file upload status= "+response.status);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log('err', err)}
    });

})
```

**PHP CODE:**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_upload_submit_docs', 'upload_submit_docs' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_upload_submit_docs', 'upload_submit_docs' );

function upload_submit_docs(){
    global $mydb;

    $response['doctype'] = $_POST['doctype'];
    $response['user'] = base64_decode($_POST['testuser']);
    $response['form_data'] = $_FILES['file_data']['name'];


    $document_file = $_FILES['file_data']['name'];

    //Define path to upload document
    $target_dir = "/wp-content/themes/upload/documents/";
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file_data']['tmp_name'];
    $target_file = getcwd().$target_dir .basename($document_file = $_FILES['file_data']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $target_file)){
        $response['status'] = 'success';
    }else{
        $response['status'] = 'fail';
    };


  echo json_encode($response);
  wp_die();

}


//Function creating sections

function html_submit_docs($docname,$datasubmit){

    $html .= '<section class="docs">';
        $html .= 
        '<div class="card_doc">
            <div class="custome-file" data-type="'.$datasubmit.'">
              <div id="label">
                Upload Your '.$docname.'
              </div>
              <input type="file" class="fileinput" name="'.$datasubmit.'" id="'.$datasubmit.'"/>
            </div>
        </div>';
    $html .= '</section>';
    return $html;

}
```